# LilyPond - dotted note chords

Tags: chords, lilypond

I have a problem with dotted note chords in LilyPond, for example:

```
\version "2.22.2"
\relative c
{
    <f' g a c>4.\arpeggio
}
```

This produces:
[image: close spaced chord with augmentation dots extending beyond the vertical range of the notes]

For the sake of presentation, I am wondering is there a method to avoid showing the dot under line 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reducing the number of augmentation dots displayed for a close position chord can be achieved by changing the number of "extra" dots that can occur (from the default 3, to 1):
`\once \override Staff.DotColumn.chord-dots-limit = #1`

See this page of the internals for more details and related settings:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/internals/dotcolumn

---

Depending on the particular voicing of the chord and where it sits on the staff, you might also need to move the dots up or down slightly:
`\once \override Staff.Dots.staff-position = #1`

See: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/internals/dots

Comment: Thank you, that was nice and neat~:)